# How to fix unknown lines being created by svg transformation

Tags: css, svg, safari

I have a loading svg icon consisting of 3 circles that rotates clockwise. It works fine and designs are correct on chrome and firefox but, on safari, circles create a weird line at a certain point (SS below). Not sure what could be causing this issue.

[image]

The code for loader svg

```
<div class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center w-full h-full fixed select-none z-50" style="left: 50%;top: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);" x-show="isLoading" x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-200" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100" x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">

    <svg width="57" height="57" viewBox="0 0 57 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#fff" class="stroke-current text-primary" style="/* stroke: salmon; */">
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill: color();">
            <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2" style="translate: (0,1);transform: translate();transform: translate(112341122121,5);">
                <circle cx="5" cy="50" r="5">
                    <animate attributeName="cy" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" values="50;5;50;50" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="cx" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" values="5;27;49;5" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </circle>
                <circle cx="27" cy="5" r="5">
                    <animate attributeName="cy" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" from="5" to="5" values="5;50;50;5" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="cx" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" from="27" to="27" values="27;49;5;27" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </circle>
                <circle cx="49" cy="50" r="5">
                    <animate attributeName="cy" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" values="50;50;5;50" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="cx" from="49" to="49" begin="0s" dur="2.2s" values="49;5;27;49" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="ml-10 text-primary text-xl">
        Loading...    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve it? Cannot figure it out.

Comment: you can search for existing webkit bugs here: https://bugs.webkit.org/ and if there isn't one, file a new one.

Comment: Can it be anti-aliasing around the edges, what happens with a ``viewBox="-1 -1 58 58"``?

Comment: Nope, that does not work. However, adding box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent; to svg does solve the issue. Not sure why it really solves the issue.